# Comma split function in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I have a parameter in which I'm having information like:

```
"item1,item2,item3,item4"
```

So this could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

I want to split it and process it individually. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What XSLT code do you already have? And what XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: The code that I m using is too long to put but yah its one of the functionality I need to add using what I said...I m getting the value in xslt from C# so there is nothing much to show related to it.... <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">

Comment: Sorry i m new to xslt...Just started learning...when u say XSLT processor wht do u mean by that...I m using some tools to build xslt...and i am making some webpart but yah i want it to be browser compatible...for all browsers...so where this xslt processor comes in?Its just for building code or where I m using it all those shud have that processor..

Comment: @AB The XSLT processor is the XSLT software you are using, eg Xalan, Saxon, .NET XslCompiledTransform, or the ones built in to web browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [exslt](http://www.exslt.org), these extensions are available for most XSLT processors.

[Here](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html) is an implementation of [str:split](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/split/str.split.template.xsl) as an XSLT template. It is called like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="values">
    <xsl:text>item1,item2,item3,item4</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:call-template name="str:split">
   <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$values" />
   <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="','" />
</xsl:call-template>
```